# Flow(cannot-resolve-module) error importing webp file into react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, flowtype, webp

Getting a flow error returned when  I import a webp image file into my react application. 
I'm using the same syntax for a png image which works correctly and cannot see what the issue is?

(using create-react-app in vscode with flow v0.129.0)

```
import test from "./assets/test.png";
import testwebp from "./assets/test.webp";
```

error message returned:
**Cannot resolve module `./assets/test.webp**

Any chance anyone has encountered anything like this before?
Have looked through other threads but not having much luck finding a solution or clear cause.
Will keep looking in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit 2021-03-20

Flow has just released webp support in version 0.147.0 so you won't need a module mapper anymore for this.

https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.147.0

---

### Original Answer

It's because flow does not understand what should be returned from a webp format. You can tell it by adding `module.name_mapper.extension` to your flow configs

https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-extension-string-string

You want to add something to the `[options]` section like the following where the assumption that importing `webp` files returns strings.

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='webp' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-mocks/empty-string.js'
```

Then you can create a `empty-string.js` file in `flow-mocks`

```
// @flow
export default '';
```

Now when you import `webp` files, flow will treat it as a string so you can get soundness if you want to pass it around or `toLowerCase` it, etc.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for replying, much appreciated. Tried out your approach but still getting the same flow type error. Cannot resolve module `./assets/test.webp`
The puzzling thing is why would flow have an issue with webP files and not have the same issue when I import files such as .png or .jpg.

Comment: I tested the same in my project, `png` has no flow errors but `webp` does by default. This is probably because webp extension isn't configured by default. What happens if you run `yarn flow` in you command line, do you get the same error or is there an error related to `cannot find module 'empty-string.js'`?

Comment: When I run ```yarn flow``` in the CLI I get the error ```Cannot resolve module ./assets/test.webp```. Thanks again for your help on this, much appreciated.

Comment: I made this with the same settings as I explained and I don't have the issue, can you let me know if it works for you? https://github.com/Brianzchen/webp-test

Comment: Hi Brian, downloaded that repo but seeing errors when I run the build or try and start the application.

```ERROR in ./src/test.webp 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)```


Guessing it's likely issues with my setup. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: wow that is odd. Are you using windows or have flow install globally by any chance? Just for reference, I'm running MacOS and only use local versions of flow

Comment: Running macOS, had a global version of flow installed which is now removed but still seeing the error after a full reinstall.

Comment: Just wanted to update that a PR has been raised with flow to add `webp` as a standard https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/8453

Comment: cool, thanks for keeping me in the loop, much appreciated.

Comment: webp support has finally landed in new version and I've edited the answer